# Issues with connecting google cloud sql postgres instance from beam pipeline

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-beam, google-cloud-sql

I've been having some issues with a connection to a Postgresql instance on Google Cloud SQL, and wanted to ask for help. I'm not sure if a solution would be to initiate a connection engine or something of the sort, but here is my issue. My code is as follows

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from beam_nuggets.io import relational_db

source_config = relational_db.SourceConfiguration(
    drivername='postgresql+pg8000',
    host='localhost',
    port=5432,
    username= USERNAME,
    password= PASSWORD,
    database= DB-NAME,
    create_if_missing=True,
)

table_config = relational_db.TableConfiguration(
            name=TABLE-NAME,
            create_if_missing=False,
            primary_key_columns=["key"],
            create_insert_f=FUNCTION,
        )

with beam.Pipeline(options= pipeline_options) as pipeline:    
update_pipe= (
    pipeline
    | 'QueryTable' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
        table= TABLE)
    | 'UPDATE DB' >> relational_db.Write(source_config=source_config, table_config=table_config)
)
```

Running the code like this has resulted in the following error:

```
RuntimeError: sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pg8000.exceptions.InterfaceError) Can't create a connection to host localhost and port 5432 (timeout is None and source_address is None).
```

I've read the documentation and some related questions on stackoverflow, where I've seen some suggestions like Private IP connectivity, or trying to authenticate with the Gcloud CLI , and other such things. But my confusion relates to the following. If I use sqlalchemy without trying to implement it in an apache beam pipeline, I don't get the same connection refusal. And one of the arguments explicitly defines the IP types to look for as Public

```
import sys  
import sqlalchemy
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes


# initialize Python Connector object
connector = Connector()

# Python Connector database connection function
def getconn():
    conn = connector.connect(
        CLOUD-SQL-CONNECTION-NAME, # Cloud SQL Instance Connection Name
        "pg8000",
        user=USERNAME,
        password=PASSWORD,
        db=DB-NAME,
        ip_type= IPTypes.PUBLIC  # IPTypes.PRIVATE for private IP
    )
    return conn

# create connection pool with 'creator' argument to our connection object function
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "postgresql+pg8000://",
    creator=getconn,
)

# interact with Cloud SQL database using connection pool
with pool.connect() as db_conn:
   
    result = db_conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text("SELECT * from users_copy LIMIT 10")).fetchall()
```

So my question is, is there a way to include the connection/engine in the Beam pipeline to avoid the error? Or do I need to change the source config arguments to include the Cloud SQL Instance connection name?

Thanks for the help and for reading my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you locked into using the `beam_nuggets.io` library?

If yes, then you can unfortunately not use the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector).

Taking a look at the [beam-nuggets code](https://github.com/mohaseeb/beam-nuggets/blob/master/beam_nuggets/io/relational_db_api.py#249) it uses SQLAlchemy under the hood which can be used by the Python Connector, however it configures the database engine purely using a database URL/URI. The Cloud SQL Python Connector requires leveraging SQLAlchemy's `create_engine` method with the [`creator`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.creator) argument. Beam nuggets would have to add support for the `creator` argument in order to support the Cloud SQL Python Connector.

An alternative to the Cloud SQL Python Connector would be to try and deploy the [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy) alongside your Beam application so that your initial code snippet would work connecting to `localhost`.

Update: I put up a [PR](https://github.com/mohaseeb/beam-nuggets/pull/51) to try and add support for the `creator` argument to `beam-nuggets`, doesn't look like the library is actively maintained though.

Comment: Thank you for your response, would the deployment of the Cloud SQL Proxy be possible for a service account? I ask because I'm developing this in a Vertex AI User managed notebook.